# Why does my while(Scanner.hasNext()) loop never exit?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I'm learning Java and building a Battleship game as a learning exercise.  I created a method to receive a set of coordinates from the user, which is entered as two integers separated by a space.  I've verified that the two integers are being read correctly, but then the program continues taking input from the keyboard, and never gets out of the while loop.  therefore, the method never returns a set of coordinates.  I've searched and read a lot about using Scanner, and I don't see what is wrong with my code.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The Scanner being passed in is `Scanner(System.in)`.

```
public static int[] getCoordinates(Scanner input, String prompt) {
    int[] coordinates = new int[2];
    boolean invalid = false;

    do {
        System.out.println(prompt + ":");
        int index = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            if (input.hasNextInt() && index < 2) {
                coordinates[index] = input.nextInt();
                index++;
            } else {
                input.next();
            }
        }
            
        if (coordinates[0] < 0 || coordinates[0] > 4 || coordinates[1] < 0 || coordinates[1] > 4) {
            System.out.println("Invalid coordinates. Choose different coordinates.");
            invalid = true;
        }
    } while (invalid);
    
    return coordinates;
}
```

What I expect to happen is for the user to enter two integers, then hit enter, and the `while(input.hasNext())` loop will exit and continue with the rest of the method.

**UPDATE:** I've managed to get the basic functionality by simply doing the following.  I'm not sure this is robust, but it will do for now.

```
int index = 0;
while (index < 2) {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        coordinates[index] = input.nextInt();
        index++;
    }
}
```

This also works well.  Thanks to @k314159!

```
String[] answer = input.nextLine().split(" ");
if (answer.length >= 2) {
    coordinates[0] = Integer.parseInt(answer[0]);
    coordinates[1] = Integer.parseInt(answer[1]);
}
```

Comment: Because your user is always supposed to be able to type one more line of input.

Comment: I'm attempting to consume any tokens left in the scanner (such as newline) before exiting this method, because it gets called multiple times.  Is there a better way to do that than using input.next()?

Comment: If this is a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` (or for example a network socket), then as long as it hasn't been closed (which will make it reach end-of-stream/end-of-file), it will block waiting for more input.

Comment: From which source are you reading? A terminal/prompt, a file, s socket ...? In the first case you have no way of distinguishing input that the user has already typed from input they will only type after after the method has returned.

Comment: The input is from Scanner(System.in).

Comment: The loop will only exit when `input.hasNext()` returns false. The only way `input.hasNext()` can return false is if the end of the stream is reached. If the stream comes from the terminal, the only way the end of the stream can be reached is if the user simulates end of stream by typing Ctrl-Z (on Windows) or Ctrl-D (on Linux).

Comment: @k314159 can you suggest a better way to implement this functionality?  In the context of the exercise, we are supposed to use a single scanner throughout the entire program, so I need a way to be able to get an input and prevent any tokens being left behind that will screw up the next one.

Comment: Input a whole line (`input.nextLine()`) and take the first two tokens from the line (`line.split()`) and discard any other tokens on that line.

Comment: For us to suggest, you should first explain much more precisely, clearly and fully what you are trying to obtain. However there a lots of examples out there of reading and validating user input, so you can probably find something useful. If you just want to get rid of the remainder of the same line (which you have not told us), it’s as simple as `input.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Why does my while(Scanner.hasNext()) loop never exit? ..."*

It's waiting for more input.
In *Java*, this is sometimes referred to as *"blocking"*.

> *"... What I expect to happen is for the user to enter two integers, then hit enter, and the `while(input.hasNext())` loop will exit and continue with the rest of the method. ..."*

Just call the *nextInt* method, twice.

```java
int[] coordinates;
boolean invalid;

do {
    System.out.println(prompt + ":");
    coordinates = new int[] { input.nextInt(), input.nextInt() };

    invalid = false;
    if (coordinates[0] < 0 || coordinates[0] > 4 || coordinates[1] < 0 || coordinates[1] > 4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid coordinates. Choose different coordinates.");
        invalid = true;
    }
} while (invalid);

return coordinates;
```

A better approach would be to check the values when adding them to *coordinates*.

```java
int[] coordinates = new int[2];
boolean invalid = true;

do {
    System.out.println(prompt + ":");
    switch (coordinates[0] = input.nextInt()) {
        case 1, 2, 3, 4 -> {
            switch (coordinates[1] = input.nextInt()) {
                case 1, 2, 3, 4 -> invalid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (invalid) {
        System.out.println("Invalid coordinates. Choose different coordinates.");
        input.nextLine();
    }
} while (invalid);

return coordinates;
```

Or optimally, evaluate the input using the *[Scanner#next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())* or *[nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())* method, and the *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))* method.

```java
int a = 0, b = 0;
boolean exit = false;
do {
    System.out.println(prompt + ":");
    try {
        a = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        b = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        if (Math.min(a, b) < 0 || Math.max(a, b) > 4) throw new Exception();
        exit = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid coordinates. Choose different coordinates.");
        input.nextLine();
    }
} while (!exit);
return new int[] { a, b };
```

Or, a *stream*.

```java
int[] coordinates = null;
boolean exit = false;
do {
    System.out.println(prompt + ":");
    try {
        coordinates
            = input.tokens()
                   .limit(2)
                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                   .peek(x -> {
                       if (x < 0 || x > 4)
                           throw new RuntimeException(); })
                   .toArray();
        exit = true;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid coordinates. Choose different coordinates.");
        input.nextLine();
    }
} while (!exit);
return coordinates;
```